# List dependencies and rank them

Tags: module, dependencies, nestjs

We have a monolith NestJs project with a lot of different modules.
You can categorize the modules in the first instance in apps and libs. Within each of these "categories" are a lot of different separate modules.

The modules depend on each other and it has become a huge spider web. We are going for a micro-service architecture but because virtually everything depends on everything.

To Detangle this spider web I want to do two things:

1. I want to see which modules depends on which and rank them by the amount of dependencies (example:
   we have: mod 1, mod 2, ... mod n

1. mod 8 (depends on mod 2, mod 3)
2. mod 3 (depends on mod 4, mod 2, mod 33, mod 9)
3. mod 6 (depends on 5 other modules)
4. ...

2. There are some modules which are imported just to use, for example, 1 function (so the remaining stuff of the module is just overhead). I want to find out if there are a lot of these functions, so I could extract them into a separate module (to avoid the before mentioned overhead).
   How could I achieve that?

I tried figuring out manually by using nx graph and looking at each module but it is just too much.

Comment: Maybe you can try with Nest.js Devtools: https://docs.nestjs.com/devtools/overview. It's a pretty new addition and I'm not sure how it will perform in a monorepo